# is there an API call to retrieve Promotion sales information?

Tags: python, api, ebay-api

I have many coupons that I use, and I would like to get the **amount of sales** I got from each one of them, I am using the [XML API](https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/Reference/eBay/index.html#CallIndex) but I couldn't find a suitable call there, am I missing it or it doesn't exists?

The data that I want to get is avaliable to get if you go into [Promotion Manager Dashboard in eBay](https://www.ebay.com/sh/mkt/promotionmanager/dashboard), I don't know how can I get it via code.

Answer (score 0):

Sellers can track the performance of their promotions with two types of reports. Call getPromotionSummaryReport and getPromotionReports to get statistics that can help you gauge your promotion activity and effectiveness, which can help you target future promotions.

If it is this what you are looking for... you can check here:

https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/sell/static/marketing/promotions-manager.html